# Access function member of base page class?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, class

Currently I'm utilizing a base page class for my website declared like so:

```
 Public Class BasePage
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
```

and subsequent pages inherit that using:

```
 Partial Class Default
     Inherits BasePage
```

I have a function in the base page class that I want to be able to use from the pages that inherit the class. The function I have is declared:

```
  Public Function GetSiteVers(ByVal parType As String) As String
```

When I attempt to call from a page that is inheriting the class:

```
 Me.GetSiteVers("Misc")
```

I get the error

```
 "GetSiteVers is not a member of Default"
```

or just

```
 GetSiteVers("Misc")
```

I get the error:

```
 'GetSiteVers' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
```

I've different declarations and Vis Studio's intellisense finds no errors and when I build the page locally I get no compiler errors. Anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Can you try name the partial class anything else than `Default` ? And corresponding `inherits` attribute of ASPX page as well?

Comment: Also, where within the page are u calling `Me.GetSiteVers("Misc")` ?

Comment: can you show the shell of basepage, too?

Comment: @Yuriy Galanter Actually I used default in this example to make it more generic and I received the same results as the other name of auth_default. It looks like this: `Partial Class auth_Default
    Inherits BasePage`

Comment: @Yuriy Galanter2 Calling the method within the default page from the page_load event.

Comment: Just to confirm - intellisense shows the funciton and project compiles without any errors. The error you're seeing happens at runtime?

Comment: @ps2goat What do you want to see from the class besides the declaration and function mentioned? The function itself doesn't call any siblings within the basepage class and is passed a string value to translate and return a string value via an HTTPcontext call. All of the other subroutines are accessible within other pages. The page_load event is declared as Protected Overrideable and page_error event is private.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter yes, there's no indication of error with intellisense and when I build the page, there are no errors shown in the message window.

Comment: Also, is `Class BasePage` in a separate .VB file? If so, which folder of your project is it located in?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter `Class BasePage` is separate from page in question and is housed in its own file in the `App_Code` directory so it is accessible to all pages in the web.

Comment: @Andrew, I would like to see as much as possible so we don't have to keep asking so many questions.  Once we answer your question, it'll be easy to tell you why we wanted to see something.

Comment: You've got all bases covered. It *should* work. Perhaps try cleaning "Temporary ASP.NET Files" folder for your respective .NET framework, rebuild the solution and try again?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter I did sort of the equivalent, I deleted the BasePage class file from App_Code and reloaded the page so the web would recompile resulting in the obvious error. Then, I copied the class file back over and reloaded the page to recompile the web and now it works! Strange behavior, but I think it was cached for some reason on the webserver and the steps taken refreshed it (or removed old temp files). Thanks for your help, I was going batty trying to pin this down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps taken to correct this were:

- Delete existing Basepage class file from `App_code` (`BasePage.vb`)
- Reload page that was throwing the error (resuting in an obvious error, but forcing a recompile of the web without the class (clears out cached temp files I assume)
- Copied back over `BasePage.vb` to `App_Code`
- Reloaded offending page and it loaded without error

I'm assuming that this is the fashion in which to clear out any cached/temp files being referred to in the web. Odd way of doing it, but when you don't have complete control of IIS I guess that's the path one has to take.